# Obtain different values ​depending on the selection criteria

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would appreciate if you could help me, since I am a novice in programming, I am wanting to obtain different values ​​depending on what I select, and that these numerical values ​​change in each box. 
For example, if I select "Loans" in the "new orders" box, the value will be: 312, in the "In process" box 180, in the "Approved" box 56, and in the "Rejected" box 25, as an example .

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="ml-auto">
<select class="custom-select">
    <option value="0" selected>Loans</option>
    <option value="1">Home appliances</option>
    <option value="2">Cable tv</option>
    <option value="3">Internet</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <!-- column -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-info text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">New orders</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium">368</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- column -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-secondary text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">In process</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium">257</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- column -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-success text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Approved</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium">86</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-danger text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Rejected</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium">25</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want select loans from the down and get the value of new order which will be 368 ? is what you mean ? You have explain a bit more what are you trying to archive and where so want those value to go or show ?

Comment: Values ​​must change in each box, by any other random numerical value

Comment: Okay sure. And you want them to be change on clicking somwhere else or by select the something else from the drop down ?

Comment: If the values ​​have to change when selecting any of the items in the select, the numerical values ​​can be any random one, the one you choose, since I am not storing anything in the database. I just want to see how it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question: You want to dynamically change the vales in the boxes based on the selection in the dropdown.

This can be done in 3 steps:

1. Read value from dropdown
2. Based on the value above, get the data to be put
3. Update the HTML with the correct id to show correct data

I am using a hardcoded dictionary, you should structure your data in a similar way to easily update the values as needed.

```js
const sampleData = {
  "0": [30, 2, 18, 6],
  "1": [435, 234, 38, 84],
  "2": [464, 34, 49, 33],
  "3": [342, 96, 60, 74]
};

const setValues = () => {
  const val = document.getElementById("selection").value;

  document.getElementById("new-orders").textContent = sampleData[val][0];
  document.getElementById("in-process").textContent = sampleData[val][1];
  document.getElementById("approved").textContent = sampleData[val][2];
  document.getElementById("rejected").textContent = sampleData[val][3];
};

// setting values initially
setValues();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="ml-auto">
    <select class="custom-select" id="selection" onchange="setValues()">
        <option value="0" selected>Loans</option>
        <option value="1">Home appliances</option>
        <option value="2">Cable tv</option>
        <option value="3">Internet</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- column -->
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="card bg-info text-white  card-hover">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">New orders</h3>
                  <div class="align-items-center">
                      <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                         <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium" id="new-orders">368</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- column -->
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="card bg-secondary text-white  card-hover">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">In process</h3>
                  <div class="align-items-center">
                      <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                         <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium" id="in-process">257</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- column -->
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="card bg-success text-white  card-hover">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Approved</h3>
                  <div class="align-items-center">
                      <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                         <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium" id="approved">86</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="card bg-danger text-white  card-hover">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Rejected</h3>
                  <div class="align-items-center">
                      <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                         <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium" id="rejected">25</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Excellent!!! that's what i wanted to do !! I keep learning hehe !! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I could help @pablo79py

Comment: Excuse me, my friend, I'm upset again. Could you help me with something new? I would really appreciate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437304/add-the-values-depending-on-the-selection-criteria

Answer (score -1):

I added classes to the spans but you could do the same with tag names
works fine for me ;)

```js
let numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for(let i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++){
  numbers[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{
  //YOU WILL GET THE NUMBER YOU CLICKED
  console.log(numbers[i].innerText);
})
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="ml-auto">
<select class="custom-select">
    <option value="0" selected>Loans</option>
    <option value="1">Home appliances</option>
    <option value="2">Cable tv</option>
    <option value="3">Internet</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <!-- column -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-info text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">New orders</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium number">368</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- column -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-secondary text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">In process</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium number">257</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- column -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-success text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Approved</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium number">86</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="card bg-danger text-white  card-hover">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Rejected</h3>
              <div class="align-items-center">
                  <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
                     <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium number">25</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Run the code to check