# Add the values ​depending on the selection criteria

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add random values, depending on the criterion, for example if I choose "Loans" and in the second criterion "Week" I would like the total summed values ​​to be shown in the table in a week, that is to say 7 days, the same if the chosen criterion was 1 month, the total values ​​would be in 31 days. Values ​​are random because this is not in a database.

```js
const sampleData = {
  "0": [30, 2, 18, 6],
  "1": [435, 234, 38, 84],
  "2": [464, 34, 49, 33],
  "3": [342, 96, 60, 74],
};

const setValues = () => {
  const val = document.getElementById("selection").value;

  document.getElementById("approved").textContent = sampleData[val][0];
  document.getElementById("rejected").textContent = sampleData[val][1];
};

// setting values initially
setValues();
//const time = {
//"0": [435, 234, 38, 84],
// "1": [55, 35, 30, 15],
// "2": [22, 18, 15, 6],
// "3": [12, 10, 10, 2],
//  "4": [8, 8, 7, 1],
// "5": [4, 3, 2, 0]
//};

//const setValues = () => {
//const val = document.getElementById("selection").value;

//document.getElementById("day").textContent = time[val][0];
//document.getElementById("week").textContent = time[val][1];
//document.getElementById("month").textContent = time[val][2];
//};

// setting values initially
//setValues();
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="ml-auto">
    <select class="custom-select" id="selection" onchange="setValues()">
      <option value="0" selected>Loans</option>
      <option value="1">Home appliances</option>
      <option value="2">Cable tv</option>
      <option value="3">Internet</option>
    </select>
    <select class="custom-select" id="time" onchange="setValues()">
      <option value="0" selected>day</option>
      <option value="1">week</option>
      <option value="2">Month</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <!-- column -->

  <!-- column -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card bg-success text-white card-hover">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Approved</h3>
        <div class="align-items-center">
          <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
            <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium" id="approved">86</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="card bg-danger text-white card-hover">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title m-b-0">Rejected</h3>
        <div class="align-items-center">
          <div class="p-t-20 text-center">
            <span class="display-4 d-block font-medium" id="rejected">25</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you describe what data you have? It would be really helpful to understand what you want to do if I could have a sample data.

Comment: The idea is that if you select, for example "Loans" and want to know how many loans were made in 7 days, the table shows the sum of the 7 days. For which I use two selectors one of which I select to know the amount of loans that I sold in 1 month, 7 days or per day. these values ​​can be random because I don't use a database. At least knowing how it would work if I select the data per week, this way I can use the same reasoning with that of 1 month. The default value should be per day

Comment: The logic for setting it is the same as here. The crucial part is aggregating the data. That should be dealth with in the DB layer so that you just get a list of values in that duration. Once you get a list, summing it up should also be taken care of in the data layer. `SUM` aggregates are there in SQL for similar tasks.